# How to get the difference in minutes of the two columns declared as timestamp

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi I want to get the difference of the two columns in minutes. To be able to get this conditions:

Timediff(current_time – device_time) > 15 minute.

I have a df of

sample_df =

| current_time | device_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-19T08:10:27.005+0000 | 2021-11-19T08:10:18.491+0000 |

```
diff_min = (sample_df
       .withColumn("diff", f.col("current_time") - f.col("device_time"))
      )
```

i tried to used the ".dt.total_seconds() / 60" but doesn't work out for me.

Comment: This is not pandas code

Comment: Yes, looks like PySpark.

Comment: It looks like your timestamp already has `YYYY-MM-DD T hh:mm:ss` so you just need to extract `mm` from both interested columns the calculate `diff_min`. So what is the point of `/60` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the timestamp to Unix timestamps and then compute the difference between those columns and then divide by 60 to get the desired output.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn(
    "date_diff_in_min", 
    (F.col("current_time").cast("long") - F.col("device_time").cast("long"))/60.
).show(truncate=False)
```